# How do you do a Transifex text search with an "or" operator?

Tags: transifex

I am tackling [a bug](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1776/) on the Japanese site and want to search for three different strings so I can link them to the community.

I would like to search for: `refiner OR explainer OR illuminator`

How can I do that with the string search in Transifex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sam from the Transifex team here. Unfortunately, the search function doesn't support operators at the moment. You'll need to search for strings individually and then share the permalink of each search result with your community.